# Is there a BCE / CE date library for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

It looks like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is the latest and most robust JavaScript date library out there, but it doesn't handle ancient dates (or dates millions and billions of years ago).

Is there anything that can do that?

Comment: Science estimates there were about 400, 22 hour days in a year 600 million years ago, from evidence in coral growth rings, but no one has a provable estimate for the length of a day or year on earth before that. For geologic times, dates mean whatever you say they do. It may be easier to move to Texas, where the universe began about six thousand years ago, which is well within javascripts date range.

Comment: It should be able to take any date defined on wikipedia and convert it into a timeline. The timeline should have upper limit on the scale of [the age of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_natural_history), and lower limit on scale of [planck's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Grand_unification_epoch). dates/periods can be defined as strings such as "1.5 Bya", "1 ns", or "between 10 and 20k BCE". It should handle relativity.

Answer (score 4):

[Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)